# How do you animate an SVG path in IOS?

Tags: ios, animation, svg

I have an SVG path like this:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1"  baseProfile="full"> 
    <path d="M47.16,66.38c0.62,1.65-0.03,2.93-0.92,4.28c-5.17,7.8-8.02,11.38-14.99,18.84c-2.11,2.25-1.5,4.18,2,3.75c7.35-0.91,28.19-5.83,40.16-7.95" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

I can render the path but can't seem to find a way to make the path animate so that it looks like it is "being draw" as if with pencil. The `animate` node works for single coords but not for paths.

I will eventually end up using this animation in an iPhone app either with a parser or with a UIWebView.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275249/how-can-i-animate-a-progressive-drawing-of-svg-path/14282391#14282391

Comment: Hi, How do you use this in iOS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try animating the ['stroke-dashoffset'](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#StrokeDashoffsetProperty) (note that you need a matching ['stroke-dasharray'](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#StrokeDasharrayProperty) with it), see [this example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/smil/pen-stroke-animation.svg). The length of the path that needs to be computed to be able to use this successfully can be fetched via script like:

```
var pathlength = yourPathElm.getTotalLength()
```

View source on the [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/smil/pen-stroke-animation.svg) to see how it's done.

Comment: Very nice example, thank you! I've been working over your example isolating only the elements that apply to just one stroke. I'm almost there except that I can't figure a couple of things: **1)** Why is it that if I remove the `translate` from your `<g>` node I can't see anything? **2)** Why did you repeat 54 twice in the style declaration for `stroke-dasharray`?

Comment: 1) because the path is defined with that offset (quick inkscape hack). You could apply the transform to the path 'd' attribute and remove it from the 'g' element. 2) just because i think it's more clear, it's alternating between dash length and gap length, but it's indeed possible to just specify a single number if they are the same (the browser will expand them to be an even number of dashes/gaps) see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#StrokeDasharrayProperty

Comment: I'm wondering I do have moves inside my path, which do reset the dash stroke. Is there a way to circumvent that? (http://www.stretchsketch.com/animate.svg)

Comment: begin="rect.click;0s".

begin attributes means, offset amount of time after which the anim will start. Please explain what is rect.click. The rectangle with id rect has no click handlers with it.

Comment: @drjerry: hmm, I'd suggest splitting the path when there's a moveto, just to make it simpler.

Comment: @rajkamal: `begin="rect.click"` means trigger the animation whenever the element with id "rect" is clicked, see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#SyncbaseValueSyntax.

Answer (score 2):

I tried for a long while to do this without having to add extra scripts to the header (that I have no idea of javascript didn't help), so here's the solution:

```
<path d="..." stroke-dasharray="">
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="" to="0" dur="1s" begin="0s"
           onload="var length = parentNode.getTotalLength();
                   parentNode.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray',length+','+length);
                   this.setAttribute('from',length)" />
</path>
```

I added extra line breaks for readability here.

This is legal in **SVG** (although not in HTML) because [the `svg:animate` element allows `onload`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/script.html#LoadEvent), which most HTML elements do not.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've rendered your SVG path, to make it look like it's being drawn with a pencil, you could simply cover it all with an opaque layer, and then animate the movement of this layer along the path.

To find the `CGPath` along which you'll move the layer you can use this library:
https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG

This will parse the SVG data into a UIBezierPath. Then:

```
SvgToBezier *myBezier = [[SvgToBezier alloc] initFromSVGPathNodeDAttr:@"M176.17,369.617c0,0,335.106-189.361,214.894,38.298s129.787,282.978,178.723,42.553C618.724,210.042,834.681,87.702,790,307.915" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768)];

UIBezierPath *myPath = myBezier.bezier;

CAKeyframeAnimation *mySVGPathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
bounceAnimLeft.duration = 3;
bounceAnimLeft.path = myPath.CGPath;

[myObjectToMove.layer addAnimation:mySVGPathAnimation forKey:@"pathAnimation"];
```

Comment: Could you give some more explanation on how to use your piece of code ?

Comment: If your path is in SVG and you want to make animation where it looks like it's being drawn, you'll first need to use the code I posted above to convert the SVG into a CGPath. Once you have the CGPath, take a look at this: http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/