# how do I animate a svg path?

Tags: animation, svg

I'm aware of this question: [how do you animate an svgpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924238/how-do-you-animate-an-svg-path-in-ios). And the provided answer has helped me but when the path is broken with a "move" the animation goes wrong. It starts parallel after each move. See  [here](http://www.stretchsketch.com/animate.svg). Is there a way to prevent this behaviour and have the animation perform sequencely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give an id to one animate element and then do `<id>`.end to start the next when the first finishes. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/FVqDq/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was not really wat I was hoping for. Now I have to split up the paths, maintain the positions etc. But i guess it is doable. Your explanation for the animate start and end was very useful! Thanks again.