# How can I animate a pie chart part from 0 to 100% in svg?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I am trying to figure out how to animate a pie chart part from 0 to 100. I can't even draw an arc that has more than 180 degrees. If I try to animate from a 1 degree angle to a 90 degree angle, instead of having a nice transition I'm getting a shape morph.

I'm trying to draw parts of the pie chart with paths like this:

```
M 100 100 l 0 -50 a 50 50 0 0 0 -20 10 z
```

My first challenge is calculating the last two numbers, the end point of the arc, and the second challenge is writing an animation that goes from a 1 deg angle to a 360 deg angle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you thought about using graphael or d3.js at all, as I would think they have a lot of work done for you ?

Comment: I am not trying to chart data. I'm trying to achieve a animation effect, however I will be using snap.svg to implement this, so, yeah, I tried using a helper framework for this. I need to know the basics first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its worth reading this answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275249/how-can-i-animate-a-progressive-drawing-of-svg-path) which has info on the dasharray effect which can be useful. That doesn't directly answer the pie question, but may give some ideas. A lot will depend on specifically how you want it animated, to whether these would work for you.

So you could draw a full circle with a string like "M 100, 100 m -75, 0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0" which draws 2 arcs.

You could also just do it with a circle. So here's a few bits, and a Snap example alongside it, as you will be using that, and its useful to compare...

```
<svg width="600" height="425">
    <path d="M 100, 100 m -75, 0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="150" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000">
        <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="600" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
    </path>
    <circle cx="150" cy="350" r="80" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="161" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000" >
        <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="600" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze">
        </animate>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

same last bit with Snap.js

```
var s = Snap(600,600);

var c = s.circle(150, 150, 80).attr({
    fill: "none",
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 161,
    strokeDasharray: "0 600 600 0",
    strokeDashoffset: 1000
});

Snap.animate(0,600, function( value ){ 
       c.attr({ 'strokeDashoffset': value })
},5000 );
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjEj8/3/) with them all on

Comment: this is a very good example. I'll take a look at strokeDasharray and see what I can do with it. In the meanwhile, I came up with an alternate solution : http://jsfiddle.net/agilius/KeLH4/

Comment: Is this the best way to do something like http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/gFnw9/19/ as well? I think my fiddle there is way more complicated than it has to be and I'm having a real hard time controlling the total duration of the animation.

Comment: If you're having common problems with timing, it could be worth taking a look at a library like Raphael or Snap. I don't think there's one case fits all, and some depends on the complexity of the SVG as to the correct solution.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687344/animating-svg-pie-chart-from-0-to-100-in-pure-smil