# Animating SVG pie chart from 0% to 100% in pure SMIL

Tags: javascript, svg, smil

How does one recreate this SVG pie chart animation in pure SMIL? I'm looking to ditch the complex JS and also be able to control the total duration of the animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/gFnw9/19/

So far this is all I got:

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/46mH2/ (thanks [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429053/ian))

But unfortunately:

- it's positioned way off the canvas (or wasn't a full circle to begin with)
- starts at 9 o'clock as opposed to 12 o'clock
- uses Snap.svg (would rather not depend on any external libs but will if I have to)

HTML:

```
<svg width="600" height="425">
    <path d="M 100, 100 m -75, 0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="150" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000">
        <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="600" dur="1s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
    </path>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
var s = Snap(600,600);

var c = s.circle(150, 150, 80).attr({
    fill: "none",
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 161,
    strokeDasharray: "0 600 600 0",
    strokeDashoffset: 1000
});

Snap.animate(0,600, function( value ){ 
       c.attr({ 'strokeDashoffset': value })

},5000 );
```

**UPDATE:**

Problem:

[image]

Should be:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can apply a trasformation on your path like so:

```
<svg width="600" height="425">
    <path d="M 100, 100 m -75, 0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="150" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000" transform="translate(75,75) rotate(90,100,100) ">
        <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="600" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
    </path>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/46mH2/1/

The rotation transformation will make it start at 12o'clock and the translate will offset it half the stroke-width so it is inside the viewbox.
Make sure you apply the transformation in the right order or you won't get the same result.

Update
yes, you can avoid both transformations:

```
<svg width="600" height="425">
    <path d="M 175, 175 m 0, -75 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,150 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,-150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="150" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000">
        <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="600" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
    </path>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/46mH2/3/

set a viewBox on your svg so you can scale the element and still get the whole image visible:

```
<svg width="600" height="425" viewBox="0 0 600 425">
    <path d="M 100, 100 m -75, 0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="150" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000" transform="translate(75,75) rotate(90,100,100) ">
        <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="600" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
    </path>
</svg>
```

If you're not scaling it proportionally check for the use of preserveAspectRatio to see which one suits you

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! Is there a way to make it start at 12 o'clock directly instead of having to rotate it though?

Comment: Before we finish this though: 1) how does one remove the animation once it's done?, 2) how does one control its size via CSS? `svg { width: N; height: N; }` just cuts it off.

Comment: One more thing---is `attributeType="XML"` really needed?

Comment: I've edited the answer for your last question.
I don't think the attributeType is necessary in this case because xml and css don't share that attribute name.

Comment: Spot on! Such a beautiful fiddle, especially compared to the one I posted. Thank you so much!

Comment: Found a slight bug with regards to the center of the circle. Please see the images attached to the original question. Might there be a way to fix it?

Comment: In addition the circle appears rugged in Chrome, whereas it's perfectly round in Firefox. Sorry to keep asking but do you know why this is?

Comment: Update: The rugged edges in Chrome is due to crbug.com/395474 for updates. I've been told I can use several paths with smaller radiuses as a workaround -- but how do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you posted in the update tag, please take a look into my comparison of 2 solutions:
To perfom the animation in solution one, 2 semicircles are rotated. In the second solution as usual the stroke-dashoffset is animated.
Both solutions are not pure SMIL but pure Web Animations API which I prefer. 
With help of the web-animations.min.js polyfill this code runs even in IE 11.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SVG mit CSS animieren</title>
  <script src="web-animations.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>SVG mit CSS animieren</h1>

<main>
<h2>Kreis in SVG - mit CSS animiert</h2>
<svg width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:10px; background: lightgray; border-radius: 50%">
  <path id="slice1"      fill="#c32e04"   stroke="none" d="M0,1 a1,1 0 0,1 0,-2 z" />
  <path id="slice2"      fill="#c32e04"   stroke="none" d="M0,1 a1,1 0 0,1 0,-2 z" />
  <path id="slice_cover" fill="lightgray" stroke="none" d="M0,1 a1,1 0 0,1 0,-2 z" />
  <script>
     const duration=5000;
     var anim11, anim12;
     var slice1=document.getElementById("slice1");
     var slice2=document.getElementById("slice2");
     function slice2_ontop() { slice2.parentNode.appendChild(slice2); }
     anim11=slice1.animate([
       {transform: 'rotate(0deg)'},
       {transform: 'rotate(180deg)'}
     ], { duration: duration/2, iterations: 1, fill: "forwards"});
     anim11.onfinish=slice2_ontop;
     anim12=slice2.animate([
       {transform: 'rotate(0deg)'},
       {transform: 'rotate(360deg)'}
     ], { duration: duration, iterations: 1, fill: "forwards"});
  </script>
</svg> 
<svg width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" style="margin-left:20px; background: lightgray; border-radius: 50%; transform: rotate(-90deg)">
  <circle id="circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.5" fill="none" stroke="#c32e04" stroke-width="1px" style="stroke-dasharray: 3.1416 3.1416; stroke-dashoffset: 3.1416"/>
  <script>
     var anim2;
     anim2=document.getElementById("circle").animate([
       {strokeDashoffset: '3.1416px'},
       {strokeDashoffset: '0px'}
     ], { duration: duration, iterations: 1, fill: 'forwards'});
  </script>
</svg> 

</main>
</body>
</html>
```