# How is it postponed to draw a path without libraries?

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to get a stage animation

I went all the path to svg

and through setTimeout I want to take turns to draw them

But I can't do it.

```js
let path = document.querySelectorAll("svg path");

path.forEach(function (el, index){
  let nl = el.getTotalLength();
  el.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `0 ${nl}`);
  
  setTimeout(function (){
    el.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `${nl} ${nl}` + index);
  },2400)
})
```

```css
path{
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 120" width="300">
  
  <path d="M20,30 100,30 290,0" />
  <path d="M20,50 100,50 290,17" />
  <path d="M20,70 100,70 290,34" />
  <path d="M20,90 100,90 290,51" />
  <path d="M20,110 100,110 290,68" />
  
</svg>
```

In my case, it turns out that all path are drawn at the same time .. And it is necessary separately

I want to get the effect of drawing a line like in smil with animate - in which lines are drawn in turn when using stroke-dasharray in javascript

https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/gOPMEWw

Teach how to do it

Comment: Why not just use SMIL then?

Comment: @RobertLongson  want to get an animation of drawing as on smil only on javascript

Comment: Yes I know, but why bother, just use SMIL. That's why it exists, to make life easier so you don't have to do low level stuff like this.

Comment: @RobertLongson  If, for example, there will be 300 pieces, SVG will reach huge sizes

Comment: So what? Browsers can and do optimise SMIL in ways they cannot optimise javascript. You can always create the SMIL elements via javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The loop runs so quickly it is effectively instantaneous, so all the resulting timeouts are 2400 ms from the same moment.  One solution is to define a variable `delay` outside of the loop and slightly increase it on each iteration of the loop:

```js
let path = document.querySelectorAll("svg path");

delay = 0;

path.forEach(function (el, index){
  delay += 500;
  let nl = el.getTotalLength();
  el.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `0 ${nl}`);
  
  setTimeout(function (){
    el.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `${nl} ${nl}` + index);
  }, delay)
})
```

```css
path{
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 120" width="300">
  
  <path d="M20,30 100,30 290,0" />
  <path d="M20,50 100,50 290,17" />
  <path d="M20,70 100,70 290,34" />
  <path d="M20,90 100,90 290,51" />
  <path d="M20,110 100,110 290,68" />
  
</svg>
```

In this case the first `setTimeout` is for 500ms, the next for 1000ms, the one after that for 1500ms, and so on.  You can adjust this to your needs.

Comment: Looking at the resulting `path` elements, you are for certain setting `stroke-dasharray` attribute, but it appears the values you are setting it to are such that the effect cannot actually be observed.  If you can describe the expected output I might be able to help you achieve it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/gOPMEWw - that's the kind of behavior I want to achieve

Comment: I believe this animation behavior is a result of the usage of the [`<animate>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate) tag being used here, not the `stroke-dasharray`...

Comment: the same result is not possible to get on js ?

Comment: It is possible, I was just not aware that that was the effect you were trying to achieve from your question.  If that is what you wish [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275249/how-can-i-animate-a-progressive-drawing-of-svg-path#14282391) provides a good example of how to accomplish it with JS.